# drop EventListener doesn't work

Tags: javascript, drag-and-drop, draggable

When I drag & drop the text, nothing happens. But the same script works when I change the event to "dragenter" or "dragleave". Did I miss anything?

```js
function handleDragDrop(e) {
  console.log("Something droped");
  dropStatus.innerHTML = "Something droped";
}

var dropZone = document.getElementById("dropZone");
var dropStatus = document.getElementById("dropStatus");


dropZone.addEventListener("drop", handleDragDrop);
```

```css
.drop-zone {
  width: 300px;
  padding: 20px;
  border: 2px dashed #000;
}
```

```html
<div id="dropZone" class="drop-zone">Drop Zone!</div>
<div id="dropStatus"></div>

<div class="" draggable="true">DRAG ME</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Need to cancel the over

```js
function handleDragDrop(e) {
  console.log("Something droped");
  dropStatus.innerHTML = "Something droped";
}

var dropZone = document.getElementById("dropZone");
var dropStatus = document.getElementById("dropStatus");


dropZone.addEventListener("drop", handleDragDrop);
dropZone.addEventListener("dragover", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  return false;
});
```

```css
.drop-zone {
  width: 300px;
  padding: 20px;
  border: 2px dashed #000;
}
```

```html
<div id="dropZone" class="drop-zone">Drop Zone!</div>
<div id="dropStatus"></div>

<div class="" draggable="true">DRAG ME</div>
```